# Xcode App repeatedly needing to be added to Accessibility

Tags: xcode, macos, applescript, accessibility, macos-catalina

Trying to AppleScript an Xcode app.  However, the AppleScript randomly complains on activation and/or running of the MyFirstImageReader.app that it can not read the menu tree of the app.  If I go into system>preferences >security>yada yada and remove/reenter the app for accessibility.  The AppleScript will normally work at least once.  If I quit MyFirstImageReader I have to repeat the accessibility again.  Why?  How can I keep the accessibility available?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is its coded in such a way that the _application bundle_ is being modified in some way. As an example, if using `property propertyLabel : expression` and `expression` is being modified/updated then the _application_ will need to be reauthorized.

Comment: I  downloaded the Apple Developer Conference code "My First Image Rader".  However, I want to save the data that the app creates in a window call "Transcript" but do not know enough code / xcode to tap into the app to append write the data to a text file that I could later process.  So, I decided to AppleScript a fast copy/paste operation.  This is were I run into the problem.  I don't see how a running app could do what you are proposing.  Any place you can point me to deepen my learning?  Again, thanks for your response.

Comment: Without, at a minimum, seeing the _code_ and possibility running what you have to see what's being modified to cause it needing to be reauthorized, sorry can't waste time trying to troubleshoot something I can't reproduce!